# Converter Unix TimeStamp para DateTime

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, conversão-de-tipo

Estou tentando selecionar a maior data da minha tabela, contudo as datas estão armazenadas no formato de Unix TimeStamp em uma coluna de tipo inteiro. Preciso fazer esta conversão pois preciso calcular a diferença entre datas em segundos.

Exemplo de Data e Unix TimeStamp respectivamente: 2019-08-02 15:00:35 = 1564758035

Estou tentando desta formar :

```
DECLARE @LastValue DATETIME = (SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME, MAX(Column_Name))
                               FROM Table_Name
                               WHERE Condição)
```

Error :

> Erro de estouro aritmético convertendo a expressão para o tipo de
>   dados datetime.

O que estou fazendo de errado ? Como solucionar ?

Comment: Tem o exemplo de um dado na tabela e sua data respectiva?

Comment: @Sorack Acabei de editar a pergunta fornecendo um exemplo.

Comment: Se suas datas estão armazenadas como UNIX Epoch time, ou seja: o número de segundos decorridos desde a zero hora de 01/01/1970, então basta pegar o maior valor e para calcular a diferença em segundos basta subtrair as duas datas, não é necessária nenhuma conversão para este cálculo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta utilizar o valor que você possui, em segundos, adicionado ao dia 01/01/1970:

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, Column_Name, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME))
  FROM Table_Name
 WHERE Condição
```

> [**What is the unix time stamp?**](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)
>
> The unix time stamp is a way to track time as a running total of seconds. This count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC. Therefore, the unix time stamp is merely the number of seconds between a particular date and the Unix Epoch. It should also be pointed out (thanks to the comments from visitors to this site) that this point in time technically does not change no matter where you are located on the globe. This is very useful to computer systems for tracking and sorting dated information in dynamic and distributed applications both online and client side.

Em tradução livre:

> O registro de data e hora do unix é uma maneira de rastrear o tempo como um total de segundos em execução. Essa contagem começa na Unix Epoch em 1 de janeiro de 1970, na UTC. Portanto, o registro de data e hora do unix é meramente o número de segundos entre uma data específica e a Unix Epoch. Também deve ser salientado (graças aos comentários dos visitantes deste site) que este ponto no tempo tecnicamente não muda, não importa onde você esteja localizado no globo. Isso é muito útil para sistemas de computador para rastreamento e classificação de informações datadas em aplicativos dinâmicos e distribuídos tanto on-line quanto no lado do cliente.